# Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 exception while using hadoop and giraph

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, giraph

I'm using a VM and have a cluster consists of 1 master and node and 3 nodes else, I installed hadoop and copy it to all nodes and deploying giraph in master but I don't know that I should to copy giraph folder too to all nodes or not!!, and I'm using real dataset wikiTalk and my command line is

> $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $GIRAPH_HOME/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-2.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner org.apache.giraph.examples.SimplePageRankComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/hduser/input/WikiTalk.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/wikiTalk11_output -w 4

but I found this exception

```
20/09/22 23:14:28 INFO job.GiraphJob: Waiting for resources... Job will start only when it gets all 5 mappers
20/09/22 23:14:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1600808538899_0008
20/09/22 23:14:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1600808538899_0008 running in uber mode : false
20/09/22 23:14:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
20/09/22 23:14:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1600808538899_0008 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1600808538899_0008_m_000002
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

20/09/22 23:14:50 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 12
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=1
        Killed map tasks=4
        Launched map tasks=5
        Other local map tasks=5
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=65129
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=65129
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=65129
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=66692096
    Map-Reduce Framework
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
```

so I don't what is the reason for this exception?!!

Comment: Look at the task logs in YARN

Comment: @OneCricketeer sorry, I'm know in hadoop, how can I find the task logs in YARN,please?

Comment: Port 8088 of your ResourceManager will open the YARN WebUI. From there, you can check recently ran applications

Comment: @OneCricketeer I found it ,so how I can find the error there is a lot of data

Comment: I don't know what you see, but there should be a list of applications. One of them matches the job ID from the output above